# Non toxic Pest control

Tags: pest-control

My wife and I are facing quite a bad situation with pests in our apartment. My wife is pregnant and I do not want to go with traditional pest control, which might be toxic.

Are there any options that I might have for non toxic pest control?

Thanks.

Comment: what type of pests?

Comment: Favorited just to see if my suspicion is wrong that you can't get rid of bugs (I'm assuming bugs since dealing with critters rarely involved poison anyway) without poisoning them.  If you didn't already have the bugs then usually the best way to keep them out is to keep everything clean so that there isn't anything to attract them in in the first place.

Comment: Pests are mosty roaches.

Comment: @Vaibhav check the edits, esp for roach control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borates are generally used for framing (termite control). Boron does have some minor toxicity, but it is generally regarded as a low toxicity pesticide. Other less common "natural" termite controls (Beauveria bassiana and orange oil) have similar toxicity levels.

Other good options for reduced toxicity treatments include baits with systemic insecticides (like ant and roach motels) and (maybe sticky or pitfall) traps with attractants (light, carbon dioxide, pheromone, or other baits). There is also diatomaceous earth, for indoor crawling bugs (not really for termites or other wood destroying bugs, though).

Edit- also, soapy water makes a decent bug spray; mix 1oz of dish detergent per quart of water. Also, you can use straight dish detergent around the edges of the floor or cabinets to help control invading crawling-bugs. This "treatment" will generally last for a few weeks. I would not advise doing this on carpet, but vinyl and linoleum should be fine; dishsoap on a hardwood floor might be ok, but it might also cause moisture damage. If you could test a small, inconspicuous area first (let it sit for a month- unless you see a problem) that would be smart.

Regarding roaches, a good bait is dog food and peanut butter. To make a roach trap, cover the outside of a straight walled container (like a coffee mug) with masking tape or cloth tape. Wipe a layer vaseline around the inside wall of the mug (not the outside). Put the bait on the bottom and place the trap in a dark area, like under the sink or behind a shelf. Be sure to clean the trap out occasionally and maintain the vaseline layer (it keeps the bugs from crawling out).

Comment: [Update] :- Started with Diatomaceous earth. Seeing mixed results as of now.

Comment: Diatomaceous earth sounds good since it acts like tiny knives and will kill any type of bug, but I've never used it since I'm afraid of possible negative effects on your lungs.

Comment: Googling US units, this translates to two tablespoons of detergent in a liter of water. (A European tablespoon is 15ml.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of cockroaches, you are going to have to kill the entire nest. I have worked in numerous rental properties in my lifetime and I have seen some very serious cockroach infestations. I have only found one true item that gets rid of roaches super fast with no smell and you would only see it if you were looking for it.

---

**[Combat Gel](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Combat-Source-KillL-Max-Roach-Kill-Gel-30g/37753990?athcpid=37753990&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=PWVUB&athieid=v0&athstid=CS020&athguid=d8699bbb-6b2-169249d534056b&athena=true)**

[image]

Wear gloves and squeeze a very small dab of this gel near places where the roaches will definitely be found: Under the edge of the stove, behind the refrigerator, under the microwave, on top of P-traps, behind toilets and near garbage cans.

As long as you wash your hands and your wife doesn't get any of this on her hands you won't have a thing to worry about. The roaches can smell this bait from a good distance. They get it on them when they eat it. Then they realize they are dying and run back to the nest for help. They get it on the other roaches and the entire nest dies. This stuff will get rid of the roaches within a few days.